# I'm new to angular mat-form, please suggest me which is best <mat-form-field> or html bootstrap form fields

Tags: angular

'I'm new to angular mat-form, please suggest me which is best  or html  bootstrap form fields'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Mat-form-field is a good option.
You can customize it as per your need and there are a lot of simple and elegant effect that 
you can plug easily. Like moving the placeholder up once you start typing in the input box.

See this for more 
https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview

Comment: is angular mat-form-field responsive

Comment: Hi @RAMA Y, maybe you'll get to read the docs. This should always be first if learning about new topics...